# BFS better locality of reference?

Tags: python, caching, garbage-collection, breadth-first-search

I read on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applications-of-breadth-first-traversal/) that one of BFS use case is garbage collection:

> 7) In Garbage Collection: Breadth First Search is used in copying
>   garbage collection using Cheney’s algorithm. Refer this and for
>   details. Breadth First Search is preferred over Depth First Search
>   because of better locality of reference

which got me thinking...is this advantage implementation dependent? More specifically, graph representation dependent? Here is my understanding of BFS better locality:

```
# Assume that node.neighbors is an "ArrayList"
for neighbor in node.neighbors: # BFS
    queue.append(neighbor)
# cache miss when reading the first element of the array
# cache hits when iterating the rest

for neighbor in node.neighbors: # DFS
    dfs(neighbor)
# worst case, with enough depth, it's possible that cache is full 
# when recursion returns (LRU), which means cache miss for every neighbor
```

**But what if `node.neighbors` is a LinkedList** (which I found true for a lot of the adjacency list examples), does BFS still possess better locality (the only other thing I can think of is that BFS uses `queue`, but I don't know how to reason its contribution to locality)?
[image]

Comment: In your mind, how does changing the implementation to a linked list affect performance?

Comment: LinkedList is not contiguous in memory, so it's possible to have a lot of cache miss even with bfs

Comment: actually after thinking for a while, I believe I got the idea wrong, the locality should be focused on the behavior difference between stack and queue, so even when using linked-list, bfs is still better...maybe I will answer my own question when I have time